# FLEX - Disable specific Tree nodes

Tags: apache-flex, tree, flex-mx

Ey guys,

I want to disable specific nodes in a `mx:Tree` component.

The dataprovider is a `XML` file, and here is a sample of that menu:

```
<nav>
    <menu label="Menu" action="" item="">
        <menu label="Item 1" action="image" item="image.png" />
        <menu label="Item 2" action="disabled" item=" " />
    </menu>
</nav>
```

In the above example, you will get a simple menu item with two childs. I want to disable the second child (if `action` is set to `disabled`...)

How can I do this?

All I need is to simply change the font color of those items, or to make the `alpha` 0.5. If its possible to also disable the clicking, then thats good, but the main focus is giving them different color or opacity.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically that's how item renderer should looks like. However it's not going to work with xml dataprovider. I recommend you to to use collection of objects then it will work fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:MXTreeItemRenderer xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                      xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                      enabled="{data.action != 'disabled'}">

    <s:Label text="{data.label}"
             color="{data.action != 'disabled'? 0x000000:0xff0000}"/>
</s:MXTreeItemRenderer>
```